# Assembly reference issue when using shared project from iOS and Android Xamarin projects

Tags: windows, xamarin, uwp, universal

I'm working on making a Universal Windows Platform version of an app made in Xamarin for iOS and Android. Like the other two projects in the solution I have added a shared project called "Lib" as a reference, but as soon as I add it I get lots and lots of errors about missing assembly references. For example  "The type or namespace name 'Serializable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". 
Does anyone have any experience with using a shared project on all three platforms that maybe can help me solve this issue? I don't know if I have been clear enough, but I hope so!

EDIT: It seems to be a issue with especially the System.dll reference and some other System.* dll's.

Comment: I usually use a portable class library to share the code between multiple platforms.  This way you can only use the classes that exist in all the platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serialize Does not exist in UWP.  Take a look at using a DataContractSerializer instead